# VS2010 with extern keyword

Tags: c++, mysql, user-defined-functions

I have the following two files:

1. foo.h
2. bar.cpp

In `foo.h` I decleare a variable `extern`.

Now, I would like to use the same variable in `bar.cpp` (after including `foo.h`).

Under VS2008 and VS2010 I get `unresolved external symbol` errors, while under Ubuntu with gcc the compilation is successfull.

(Namely, I'm trying to compile the following source code[:http://www.fromdual.com/using-mysql-user-defined-functions-udf](http://www.fromdual.com/using-mysql-user-defined-functions-udf); foo.h refers to srv0srv.h and bar.cpp refers to the source code. All includes are in place, compilation is a success, linking falls)

What might the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that the afformentioned symbol has to be exported (via dllspec) from the dll, to be visible from outside. Only the extern keyword did not allowed it to be seen from outside.

Answer (score 3):

The *extern* keyword indicates to the compiler that the variable following it is already declared somewhere else. It does not actually allocate space for the variable. If you want to create a global variable which you can use by including a header file (which is generally a bad idea, by the way), you can do it in the following manner.

In foo.h:

```
extern int myVar;
```

in foo.cpp:

```
int myVar;
```

myVar is now located in foo.cpp, but the extern statement in foo.h allows code in other files (such as bar.cpp) to access it by including foo.h.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `extern` to declare a variable(a global variable in other source objects or files), you actually tell compiler to look for the variable's definition somewhere else. In this case, you need to provide another source file that defines `int myVar`.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable has to have a reference somewhere in one of the source files. By the `extern` keyword you are only telling that "there is a variable" but linker has to know the location of it. While you are compiling the source, it will create references for variables etc. Linker will link according to these references. If you do not actually create a reference to a variable linker will not be able to find the reference, so it will give error. If you use `extern` you are saying that do not create a reference to this variable or any other thing here. But there has to be a reference to it at somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks! What I don't understand, why does the code compile, but doens't link in VS2010, and why does it work with gcc under linux?